# Add/Remove classes if specified class exists on different element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On [my site](https://esthersunriseofficial.com/), I am trying to achieve a fadeInUp effect for my sub-menu when I hover over the menu items in my navbar and a fadeOutDown effect when the mouse leaves from hovering over the menu item (like on [this site](https://learts.thememove.com/reblended-dish/)). I already have the animations set up and I have written some Javascript that's gotten me a little bit closer to my desired result, but the logic behind it is wrong, so it's all buggy. This is my current Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.elementor-nav-menu li.menu-item a').hover(
      function () {
        $('ul.sub-menu').removeClass('animated fadeOutDownSmall');
        $('ul.sub-menu').addClass('animated fadeInUpSmall');
      },
      function () {
        $('ul.sub-menu').removeClass('animated fadeInUpSmall');
        $('ul.sub-menu').addClass('animated fadeOutDownSmall');
      }
    );
  });
```

So basically, when I hover over the menu item, it adds the "fadeInUpSmall" class to the ul element that has the class "sub-menu" and when my mouse leaves from hovering over the menu item, it removes the class "fadeInUpSmall" and adds the class "fadeOutDownSmall". You can see how that wouldn't work, as if I move my mouse to navigate the submenu/megamenu, they start glitching out, fading in and back out etc. However, when I hover over a menu item that has a sub-menu, you can see in inspect element that the class "highlighted" gets added to the respective 'a' tag. So, my question is, how can the Javascript code that I provided be modified so that it finds if the class "highlighted" exists on the 'a' element and adds/removes the fadeInUpSmall and fadeOutDownSmall classes respectively?

Comment: If this is all supposed to happen when you hover. I think you should try and accomplish your goal with CSS.   Without further context of what you'r trying to accomplish or a visual, this question is hard to follow. Is this to show Dropdowns on hover? Is this just to make some text appear from the bottom when we hover? Your function is firing both functions on hover

Comment: I'm trying to give my submenus a fadeInUp effect when hovering over the navigation menu items and when the mouse moves away from hovering over the menu item, the submenu has a fadeOutDown effect. I did send an example of the effect I'm trying to go for, as well as a link to my site and the Javascript code to show my progress in trying to achieve the effect.

Comment: What about mouseEnter and mouseLeave?

Comment: I'll have to do some research on that. I'm not very good at Javascript..

Answer (score 1):

Mouse enter and mouse leave. 
MouseEnter
[Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)
[Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event)
Has Class 
[Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```
$('ul.elementor-nav-menu li.menu-item a').addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {'
  if($( "#mydiv" ).hasClass( "foo" )){
    $('ul.sub-menu').removeClass('animated fadeOutDownSmall')
    $('ul.sub-menu').addClass('animated fadeInUpSmall')
  }
})

$('ul.elementor-nav-menu li.menu-item a').addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
  $('ul.sub-menu').removeClass('animated fadeInUpSmall')
  $('ul.sub-menu').addClass('animated fadeOutDownSmall')
})
```

It may need to be used vice versa, depends on how you want to use it.

CSS could work like this.

```
.dropdown{
  height:0%;
  opacity:0;
  transition: height 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease 0.5s;
}
.dropdown.active:hover {
  height:100%;
  opacity:1
}
```

Comment: I would also limit this down to adding a class on mouse enter and removing that same class if mouse leave. Good Luck!

Comment: I'm not sure this would work any differently to the code I originally provided? I think the way to get what i'm trying to achieve to work is to find if the "highlighted" class exists in the "a" element and if it does, then add the classes "animate" and "fadeInUpSmall" to the ul element that has the class "sub-menu". I'm not sure if that makes sense or not? But is something like that possible?

Comment: Hard to understand without a visual but here is what you should use to search if a element has a class in JQuery. https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Comment: I posted a hasClass Edit